# How to read IConfiguration before creating builder in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm using library that creates builder in this way

```
var webApiOptions = new AkaAppOptions<ApiOptions>(ApplicationId, authenticationType);
var builder = new AkaAppBuilder<ApiOptions>(args, webApiOptions);
```

now this builder contains `IConfiguration` that I need.

My problem is that I need to read configuration to know what kind of `authenticationType` it is. this happens before I have a `WebApplicationBuilder`.

My options are to create temporary `WebApplicationBuilder`, read configuration and then create this library builder, drawback here is memory I guess.

And another option is to read `appsettings.json` manually to get that information/ drawback is memory and memory environment appsettings?

Which one to read

So for example I would do something like this to create temporary builder and than the one I need

```
var tempBuilder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var useExternalAuth = tempBuilder.Configuration.GetSection("ExternalAuth").Exists();
var authenticationType = useExternalAuth ? AuthenticationType.ExternalService : AuthenticationType.Service;

var webApiOptions = new AkaAppOptions<ApiOptions>(ApplicationId, authenticationType);
var builder = new AkaAppBuilder<ApiOptions>(args, webApiOptions);
```

Are there any other options?

Comment: Please give an example of how you want to use it. Often the configuration options of the extension methods to add things to the builder offer a builder context, from which you can access the configuration. So the answer depends on the specific use case

Comment: Your design choices kind of limit the flexibility you have. However, we cannot help you there as you are not showing a [mcve]. Usually one would use an [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options) for something like this.

Comment: @JHBonarius It absolutely does, thanks. I did provide example and since this is program.cs this is all the exmaple I can provide. can't use options pattern here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is only about the (temporary) configuration, you can set up a `ConfigurationBuilder` and add the required providers, e.g.:

```
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
// ... use temporary config
```

By calling build, the `IConfiguration` object is assembled and you can use it during the setup phase of your application.

For details on the configuration concepts in .NET Core, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration).

Comment: Can't you just tag a dupe? Or do you need the points?